# comparison of variables string and number in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

```
Run Keyword If    "${numRows1}"=='None'  Set Variable  0    ELSE    ${numRows1}=>0  Set Variable ${numRows1}

Log     ${numRows1}
```

how can I compare the values? and retrieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
...    ELSE    ${numRows1}=>0
```

This part here looks like another comparison, thus you probably meant `ELSE IF`.